# Is there anyway to detect lowest voltage of a signal like capacitor and diode do for the high one?

Tags: voltage, signal, voltage-detector

Is there any simple (not the best one) way to detect the lowest value of a signal, like a diode and capacitor detect the peak value, I want to do it for detect the lowest value of a signal.

Comment: You should basically just reverse the diode.

Comment: So you have to first charge the capacitor to the max value right? isnt there any problem with current flowing in that direction?

Comment: Can you put up the schematic you're thinking of?

Comment: Look for a peak detect circuit.  (the "peak can have either polarity... you'll have to reverse the diode as Justin said.)

Comment: What do you mean by"lowest value"? - Do you mean the most negative value or the lowest level of an AC signal such as audio?

Comment: The lowest of a positive signal +5v-0v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzVA9C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Press and release the `START` button when you want to monitor the circuit. `MIN` will be the minimum voltage output (less the [forward diode drop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10962/what-is-forward-and-reverse-voltage-when-working-with-diodes)) since start was last released.

Comment: Nice :), so you press the button the capacitor charge, then when you have a lowest value than the capacitor in V1, the capacitor discharge right?

Comment: Exactly. But remember that there is always a  forward voltage drop across a diode, so you must account for this when reading MIN.