# Motor voltage LED indicator is dead

Tags: led, pwm, ballast

I built an ESC for my Raspberry Pi.  This ESC has LED indicators.  The problem is that the motor LED indicator that indicates modulated 5 V  is dead after days.  This happened to two models.  One has a blue LED with 220 ohm series resistor.  The other has a red LED with 220 ohm series resistor as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a schematic?  470 ohms should be giving you ~6mA through a 2.1V LED, less through a higher-voltage (blue) one, so you're fine there.  You also have what appears to be a recirculating diode, but it also appears to be a 1N4001 or something similar, which could be the issue.  Also, none of those resistors look like they're 470 ohms.

Comment: You should post your schematic.

Comment: i juste posted the schematic , it is the same just 5V input LED indicator and step up module (bule circuit) not drawn

Comment: My guess is that the reverse voltage pulse from your motor is exceeding the reverse voltage limit of the LED, even with the recirculating diode.  Try putting another diode rated for, say 50V, in series with the LED.

Comment: @vir they are 470 ohm just the image editor make the purple line looks like brawn.

Comment: @vir  does small size Schottky diode in series with LED can solve this ? besides i really need to know the reason behind this and find the exact solution

Comment: Any capacitor bank or clamp on your 5V/1 rail when you are breaking on freewheeling your motor?

Comment: The LED on the PWM input should also have a series current-limiting resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The failure mode of LEDs are as follows:

1. Thermal runaway - this can't really happen unless your 5V goes way up, due to R5.
2. Reverse-breakdown - the likely scenario. Both D1 and LED3 can act as flyback diodes. While D1's VF is lower (1.03V), LED3 is directly attached to the motor.

I would redesign your indication LED on the high side of Q1 away from the flyback, or maybe replace R5 with two 110Ω resistors on the anode and cathode to make some sort of voltage divider.

Answer (score 0):

That flyback diode is pretty big, and slow.  You don't say how much current you are drawing, but from 5V, I don't imagine it's very much.
I'd look for a smaller diode, that is more appropriately sized, it can be 10x faster at turn on, eg. BAT54A.  If the flyback diode takes too long to turn on, then it might as well not be there at all, as other parts of the circuit are still going to see high voltages.  There is also the MBR series of Schottky diodes that can handle more power then the BAT54 series.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is an LED put across a flyback diode. I will elaborate.

If in theory there is nothing wrong, in practice the main thing that matters is the turn-on speed of the big flyback diode. If this is slightly slower than the maximum pulse duration duration allowed of a given maximum reverse voltage of the LED, you are stressing the LED itself.

For example, a standard red LED like the [TLUR6401](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83171/tlur640.pdf), allows a maximum reverse voltage of 6V. Additionally, there is no specification on how resistant it is with such a breakdown voltage, so you better stay away from this condition. Now, in your circuit you might have 100s of volts in spike, and depending on the spike rising shape and duration, it might be faster than the flyback diode turn-on time, hence releasing most of the flyback pulse will be on both the LED (in reverse) and the flyback diode (forward direction, which is what makes it conducting, eventually).

Is not the best place to put an LED indicator.

Comment: I checked the BYV29-400 diode and it is a fast recovery one. But LED may be even faster and a reverse voltage can occur. My suggestions: [1] Use another LED backwards, as a flywheel to the existing LED. If by any chance it Lights-up, then BYV29 is not fast enough, but problem is solved (or shunted). [2] Bypass the LED with a 100nF ceramic cap, that with existing R5=220R will double as a RC snubber.